# C fgets string length not limited to input

Tags: c, buffer, stdin

I'm confused how even though the char array `mystring` I provided can only be upto 5 characters long, the length can exceed 5 if `fgets` is supplied with a larger limit.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char mystring[5];

    fgets(mystring, 10, stdin);

    printf("len: %d", strlen(mystring));
}
```

If I input 8 or more characters and press enter, the length of `mystring` is 9. How does that happen considering the array `mystring`'s length is set to 5?

Comment: This is undefined behavior. What happens with UB can't be explained.

Comment: Whatever is on the stack after mystring is being overwritten.  This is not a safe operation.  The second argument to fgets should be: `sizeof (mystring)` so that this does not happen.

Comment: You fib (tell lies) to the compiler; the compiler gets its own back by fibbing to you.  You said the array was 10 bytes long; it wasn't.  You fibbed; you got what you deserved!

Comment: Try to understand that C is a compiled language.  When you compile your program, it is translated directly into machine instructions.  The training wheels are off.  If you write past the end of an array, it may seem to work (up to a point), it may crash, or anything else might happen.  It's undefined behavior.  It doesn't emit code for each and every array reference to see if you're indexing outside of the array bounds.  If you want that, you can use an interpreted language that makes those checks for you.

Comment: C arrays are quite unlike arrays in other languages. Same for strings. It's not entirely hyperbole to say C doesn't have arrays (or strings), only pointers with some sugar on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does that happen considering the array mystring's length is set to
> 5?

Once the abstract state machine reaches an undefined behaviour, no further assumption about the continuation of the execution can be made.

See: [Undefined, unspecified, and implementation-defined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/20017547).

Consider:

```
// fgets(mystring, 10, stdin);
fgets(mystring, sizeof mystring, stdin);
```

**Aside:**

`strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`. The call to `printf()` invokes undefined behaviour as the format specifier doesn't match the corresponding argument.

```
// printf("len: %d", strlen(mystring));
printf("len: %zu", strlen(mystring));
```

Comment: The OP seems to understand perfectly well that they _shouldn't_ provide a larger size that the size of the buffer, but rather asking why it "works." Presumably providing that input is an academic experiment.

Comment: @Chris Acknowledged.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* tell `fgets` to read 10 bytes when you only have 5 valid bytes to read into. But then you're in the realm of [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) where the program might "work" as expected, or anything else might happen.

If your program is working even with this undefined behavior, it's likely but by no means certain that your program has been reserved much more space than five bytes, so writing beyond the end of the array doesn't actually cause a runtime error. **Don't count on this.**

As an example, your code, when compiled on my computer, does not escape this fate.

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char mystring[5];

    fgets(mystring, 10, stdin);

    printf("len: %d", strlen(mystring));
}
$ gcc test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:9:19: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("len: %d", strlen(mystring));
                  ~^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  %ld
$ ./a.out
hello world foo bar
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Note: The warning can be silenced by using the `%zu` format specifier for an argument of type `size_t`.

Comment: Which version of GCC recommends `%ld` rather than`%lu` for the format (or `%zu`)?  That's an odd choice since it expects a signed long and the message says `size_t` is equivalent to `unsigned long`.